# Register Taxonomy not working fine

Tags: wordpress

taxonomy is register under product post type.. check this code

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_custom_taxonomies', 0 );

function create_custom_taxonomies() {
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Brands', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Brand', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Brands' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Brands' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Brand' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Brand:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Brand' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Brand' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Brand' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Brand Name' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Brand' ),
);
$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'brand' ),
);
register_taxonomy( 'brand', 'products' , $args );
 }


//creating a custom post type that is using 'brand' taxonomy
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'products',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Products' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product' ),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'products'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Product'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edyt Product'),
        'new_item' => __('New Product'),
        'view_item' => __('View Product'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Product'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    ),
    'taxonomies' => array('brand'),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    )
);

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

When i print all taxonomies. it shows me this result.. 
why this happen please help me

```
  array (size=5)
 'category' => string 'category' (length=8)
 'post_tag' => string 'post_tag' (length=8)
 'nav_menu' => string 'nav_menu' (length=8)
 'link_category' => string 'link_category' (length=13)
 'post_format' => string 'post_format' (length=11)
```

I am trying multiple time using demo code extra but result is same.. only wordpress default taxonomies showing..

Comment: Do you get any errors in your php error log?

Comment: No i am not getting any error

Comment: I have installed fresh wordpress then added that above code in function.php.
but not working..

Answer (score 0):

On line two remove `enter code here`. This causes your code to fail. I've tested it on my own Wordpress install. When I removed that, everything worked out fine.

I am also wondering what function you use to print all the taxonomies. When do this: `var_dump(get_taxonomies());`, I get the Brand taxonomie returned aswel.

`array(6) { ["category"]=> string(8) "category" ["post_tag"]=> string(8) "post_tag" ["nav_menu"]=> string(8) "nav_menu" ["link_category"]=> string(13) "link_category" ["post_format"]=> string(11) "post_format" ["brand"]=> string(5) "brand" }`

`get_taxonomies()` is the correct function to do this.

Comment: i am just checking taxonomies works fine when i try to print in template or any where else except function.php.

please try to print taxonomies in function.php

Comment: can you help me.
do you have team viewr? 
because i don't know why not working for me..

Comment: I Don't have time for that the upcomming hours, maybe if you're still facing this issue later today I can help you out. Add: kevinvhengst on skype if you will. I the mean time try to use `var_dump(get_taxonomies());` and under that `die()` and check the result.